Issue regarding the AA360 Pop up handle on Excel
We were having an error " Unable to open the excel file, in the aa360, the situation is at first the bot will successfully opens the excel file by action open and assigning session as "sessionshipshareonline", and after that we will encounter an pop up and the session will be lost, means we cannot able to perform any actions on the excel that we opened, How to handle this  in aa360
We tried to reopen the file after handling the pop up in catch block, but it is not working in prod, but it is working in dev.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

if you could read the description I mentioned I asked that how to handle that pop up because we were having issues with that.
